# How to factor $(x^5+1) (x^5-1) $

Tags: factoring

I have this:

$ (x^5+1) (x^5-1) $

And I don't know how to continue factor.

Geogebra's Factor says:

$(x+1)(x-1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$

Comment: Are you factoring over $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @JamesHarrison $\mathbb{Q}$, probably.

Comment: @JamesHarrison I don't know what you say, or yes, but I don't have a selection. I'd like it to be like Geogebra's result so I think I need it in N

Comment: The factors of $(x^5+1)$ are covered in [Question 138382](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/the-roots-of-t51).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $-1$ is a root of $x^5+1$, we know that it is divisible by $x+1$.  Likewise, since $1$ is a root of $x^5-1$, we know that it is divisible by $x-1$.  You can use polynomial long division to obtain the other factors.

Comment: Thanks, from what you said I remembered Gauss table, then did that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$x^n-1=(x - 1)[x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} + ... + x^2 + x + 1] $$

Comment: Thanks, I noted that $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ cannot be factored, is it true? how do I know WHEN something cannot be expressed as factors?

Comment: The divisors of the constant term, $1$, are $\pm 1$. So, you have to apply the division of $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ and $x-1$ and the division of $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ and $x+1$. When the remainder is not equal to $0$, then it cannot be expressed as factors.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to factor these polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$.

What you need is to check that $f(x)=x^{p-1}+\ldots+1$ is irreducible for any prime $p$. To see this, consider $f(x+1)=\frac{(x+1)^p-1}{x}$ for which [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) works.