# How do I solve the following equation: $z^4+z^3+z+1=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an existing method to solve the following equation:
$z^4+z^3+z+1=0$?

Comment: $z=-1$ is one solution. It factors twice, so divide out $(z+1)^2$ and you get a quadratic for the other solutions.

Comment: Related: [The roots of $t^5+1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/the-roots-of-t51/). Note that $z^5 - 1 = (z-1)(z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1)$ and $z^5 + 1 = (z+1)(z^4 - z^3 + z^2 - z + 1).$

Comment: Also, even without the nice factorizations, there's a method to solve this, as fourth-degree polynomials have exact closed-form solutions

Answer (score 8):

Hint: 
$$z^4 + z^3 + z + 1 = z^4 + z + z^3 + 1 = z(z^3+1) + z^3 + 1 = (z+1)(z^3 + 1)$$

Comment: Hah! Nice observation. +1.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: we have $$z^3(z+1)+z+1=(z+1)(z^3+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

As @David observed, since this polynomial is front-to-back symmetrical (the $z^2$ coefficient is in the middle, so its presence or absence doesn't matter), and a general method applies to cut the degree in half, as follows. Divide through by $z^2$ to get $z^2+z+{1\over z}+{1\over z^2}=0$, and let $w=z+{1\over z}$. Since $w^2=z^2+2+{1\over z^2}$, the equation becomes $w^2-2+w=0$ or $w^2+w-2=0$. Since this is quadratic, we solve it easily... $w=-2, 1$. Then $z+{1\over z}=-2$ and $z+{1\over z}=1$ give subsequent quadratics in $z$ (in this case).

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach:**

We see that $0$ does not satisfy the equation, so we can divide by $z^2$ to get the equivalent equation
$$z^2+z+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}=0\tag{1}$$
By making $u=z+\frac{1}{z}$ we get
$$u^2+u-2=0$$
The roots of this are $-2$ and $1$. Now we only need to solve
$$\color{blue}{z+\frac{1}{z}=-2}\qquad \text{and}\qquad\color{blue}{z+\frac{1}{z}=1}$$

Answer (score 1):

When $z\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$z^4+z^3+z+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(z+1)(z^3+1)=0$$

---

So, we get the following equations:

- $$z+1=0\Longleftrightarrow z=-1$$

Or:

- $$z^3+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z^3=-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z^3=e^{\pi i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z=\left(e^{\left(2\pi k+\pi\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z=e^{\frac{1}{3}\left(2\pi k+\pi\right)i}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and  $k:0-2$