# Complex quartic factorisation

Tags: quartics

Answer: I'm really not sure how to factorise.  I understand that z.z* gives 2Re(z) but it's still not clear to me how it works.

[image]

Comment: For part of your question: Recall the Factor Theorem from precalculus (school mathematics) -- If $r$ is a zero of the polynomial $P(x),$ then $x-r$ is a factor of $P(x).$ Note that $x = -1$ is a zero of the polynomial $x^5 + 1.$ Now use high school algebra to find the quotient when $x^5 + 1$ is divided by $x-r = x - (-1) = x+1.$ Also, see the question [The roots of $t^5+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/138382/13130).

Comment: Please use MathJax to write mathematics here. It is given when you signed up. Wat does  z* mean? Does it mean $\;\overline z=$ the complex coonjugate of $\;z\;$ ? Because if it does then what you wrote is false.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{w^5+1}{w+1}=?$$

For $c,$ use [Quadratic substitution question: applying substitution $p=x+\frac1x$ to $2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x)

Comment: Also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/138933/13130).